# What is the active voice of "might be affected"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, active-voice

I was reading about poisonous gases then I read there if this gas affects the insects now so humans "might be affected" by this toxic gas in coming time and one more thing in this sentence I think author wants to speak about future chances, so what is active voice of this "might be affected" in this sentence referring to future probability?

Comment: Humans might be affected by gasses = Gasses might affect humans.

Answer (score 2):

Transform *might be affected* into active preserving *might* which is used to express probability and add *affect* (infinitive) which we usually put after modal verbs. Use the object *this toxic gas* as a subject and the subject *humans* as an object.

> This toxic gas might affect humans.

Comment: Can I write this sentence " this gas will affect" in this way- "this gas might affect"?

Comment: It would be grammatical but it would change the meaning and wouldn't correspond to the initial sentence